# How to apply a mask filter to current framebuffer in OpenGL ES 2

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, mask

Let's say i have a 2D game full of sprites, i draw my sprites with a very simple shader like:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
varying vec2 vTexPos;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTexPos);
}
```

Then, at a certain point, i want to render an area of my current scene in grayscale to apply then some text on top (see example below), so, let's say that i have a vector with the mask, how the shader will look like? how do i access in Android OpenGL 2 current framebuffer to filter it?

[image: current scene]  [image: expected result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how do i access in Android OpenGL 2 current framebuffer to filter it?

here is a link to blogpost, which explains about settingup framebuffer and render to frame buffer
http://opengles2learning.blogspot.in/2014/02/render-to-texture-rtt.html

once you render your scene to texture, you can apply filters.

Comment: Thanks, great tutorial, but since i need to edit current FB couldnt i just change gl_FragColor? I mean, is gl_FragColor populated when i draw with data from previous draw calls?

Comment: yes, you can use gl_FragColor of current FB and change color to gray scale. it will be easier, if you are rendering total scene in one call.
I assume, you are rendering each sprite separately. in that case  you may have to pass the area, which you want to show in gray.

Comment: I am rendering in one call and its ok for me to just call the filter shader at the end of the pass, will try this, thanks!